# Windows 10: Issue with 'Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607'

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-desktop-computer

I received **Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607** on 14th September and since then Windows freezes frequently.

Is it just me or is it a Windows issue that others are also experiencing? Any solutions to this?

I am using ThinkCentre E73 Desktop.

Thanks

Comment: It is just you.  You should roll back to Version 1511 then attempt the upgrade again.

Comment: It's not just you. Lots of others are experiencing it. Solution is different depending on the exact cause though.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, @PotatoCat. As suggested, I will roll back to 1511 for the time being.